# Is disabling and then rebuilding index optimize bulk load

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, etl, database-performance

I have a process where in I have to load data to destination. Source is have around 8 millions records and round 5 columns(HASH string) on which Non-Clustered index build. So when I have to load data then the index are disabled first and then load starts and then rebuild. But this process still taking around an hour.

I want to optimize this process to improve performance to reduce load time.

Comment: Is the destination empty? If not, how many rows?

Comment: also, are you disabling index on source or destination?

Comment: No its not. It also contain around 5-6 million records. Yes it has same index

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then please [edit] your question to provide more details. Many things can affect bulk load throughput. Certainly disabling then re-enabling nc indexes can help. But so can many other things.